# c# array has always the length of 0

Tags: c#, xml

the length of setting is always 0, so the code jumps to the return of the if statement  which shouldn't be and i can't figure out why, poperty is set as "TreatWarningsAsErrors" 
I need to compare the value of the node specified in propertyName string.

```
public string CheckSettings(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName, string propertyName)
    {
        var setting = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants(propertyName) select doc).ToArray();

        if (setting.Length == 0)
        {
            return groupName + ": " + propertyName + " is missing";
        }

        var allOk = setting.All(n => n.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return allOk ? null : groupName + ": " + propertyName + " has wrong state.";
    }
```

example xml

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\AlfaStandardXmlManifest\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
<DocumentationFile>..\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\AlfaStandardXmlManifest\AlfaStandardXmlManifest.XML</DocumentationFile>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\..\..\Build\FxCopSoftship_ZeroTolerance.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Added the xml load and settigns check call:

```
 var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(projectFilePath);
        XNamespace nameSpace = xmlDoc.Root?.Name.Namespace;
        if (xmlDoc.Root != null)
        {
            var groups = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(nameSpace + "PropertyGroup").ToArray();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                result.Add(CheckSettings(group, GroupName(group), "RunCodeAnalysis"));
                result.Add(CheckSettings(group, GroupName(group), "TreatWarningsAsErrors"));
```

Here is what the debugger gave me for group

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\AlfaStandardXmlManifest\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  <DocumentationFile>..\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\AlfaStandardXmlManifest\AlfaStandardXmlManifest.XML</DocumentationFile>
  <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\..\..\Build\FxCopSoftship_ZeroTolerance.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
  <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: `ToArray()` can never return null.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @SLaks the code always seem to jump into the return inside the if statement which it shouldn't

Comment: That's not the same as it returning null, is it? That implies there are no results, which is a bit different. I'd guess your query is incorrect, the name likely has a non-default namespace. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Apparently, Descendants() is probably not what you want because it returns all nodes that are children to the given node as well as children of those children... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx You might want to use Nodes() instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i edited the question to clear up any confusion

Comment: You're probably missing an XML namespace.

Comment: I tested your code, and it's not falling into the if, it is returning the last line `pg: TreatWarningsAsErrors has wrong state.`

Comment: PS: i used "pg" as the groupName and your xml is missing the closing of the PropertyGroup Root node

Comment: @Magnetron its always falling into the if when i debug it im super confused

Comment: Check if in the `CheckSettings` call you're passing the right string (TreatWarningsAsErrors), maybe there is a typo, or a white space. I put your xml in a string named `xml` and use `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml)`. Then i called `CheckSettings(doc.Root,"pg","TreatWarningsAsErrors")`. It worked.

Comment: @Magnetron i use XDocument.Load(xml) but that shouldn't make a difference right ?

Comment: @Pagodatree You use `Load` if the xml is in a File, and it takes the path to the file. If the xml is in a string, you must use `Parse`

Comment: @Magnetron I use the path to the file and it is loaded correctly... I am still confused why I always fall into the if also checked for spelling errors or whitespaces....

Comment: Post the piece of code where you load the XML and call the `CheckSettings`.

Comment: @Magnetron added the calls

Comment: Try this, change to `var temp1 = propertyGroup?.Descendants(propertyName).ToList();` `var setting = (from doc in temp1 select doc).ToArray();` and Put a break point in `var setting`, and check the values of `temp1` and `setting`. If any of them is empty, check the value of `propertyGroup`, it must be the xml you posted.

Comment: @Magnetron the count of temp 1 is 0 even though the nodes are there, just checked the xml in the debugger

Comment: Put also a break Point just after `var groups`  and check the elements in the `groups`

Comment: @Magnetron thanks for being so patient anyway, i added the data that is contained in group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most MSBuild project files have an XML namespace (`xmlns="..."` in the root element), which applies to all names in the XML.

You need to include this namespace in your element name:

```
XNamespace ns = "...";
XName name = ns + "...";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem, like SLaks said, is with the namespace. In your CheckSettings, inside Descendants you're missing the Namespace:

```
XNamespace nameSpace = propertyGroup.Name.Namespace;
var setting = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants(nameSpace + propertyName) select doc).ToArray();
```